# sed command in Dockerfile wont be executed or is overwritten

Tags: linux, apache, docker

I want it to run apache in a docker container as the same user as the one I'm using on my host system. Thus I own the files on my host to edit them and apache (PHP) can create folders etc..

**EDIT:** I got the sed command to work with by changing it a little:

```
RUN sed -rie 's|export APACHE_RUN_USER=.*|export APACHE_RUN_USER=wipster|g' /etc/apache2/envvars
RUN sed -rie 's|export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=.*|export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=wipster|g' /etc/apache2/envvars
```

But when checking by using top, apache is still running as www-data.

**My Dockerfile**:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN adduser wipster --disabled-password --disabled-login --gecos ""

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER wipster
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP wipster

RUN sed -i "s#APACHE_RUN_USER:=.*#APACHE_RUN_USER:=wipster}#" /etc/apache2/envvars \
    && sed -i "s#APACHE_RUN_GROUP:=.*#APACHE_RUN_GROUP:=wipster}#" /etc/apache2/envvars

RUN    apt-get -qqy update \
    && apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev libpng-dev re2c libmcrypt-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libc-client2007e-dev libkrb5-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev vim strace unzip g++

RUN touch /var/www/html/php-error.log
RUN chown wipster:wipster /var/www/html/php-error.log

RUN    docker-php-ext-install bcmath mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip curl pcntl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap \
    && docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install ldap

# Install xhprof from tideways.
RUN curl -L https://github.com/tideways/php-xhprof-extension/archive/v5.0-beta2.tar.gz | tar xz && \
    cd php-xhprof-extension-5.0-beta2/ && \
    phpize && \
    ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug-2.7.2 \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis xdebug opcache tideways_xhprof

# /usr/local/etc/php
ADD config/crm.php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
ADD config/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
ADD config/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
ADD config/opcache-blacklist /usr/local/etc/php/
ADD config/xhprof.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/

RUN a2enmod headers expires deflate rewrite

# xdebug cli debugging
RUN export XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_port=9000 remote_host=192.168.1.144 remote_connect_back=0"
RUN export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=wipster-dckr"

EXPOSE 80

VOLUME ["/var/www"]
```

The problem is when I connect to the container via ssh and check /etc/apache2/envvars it still has www-data as the run user. I used the same Dockerfile on an Alpine Linux with the php:7.1-apache and it worked just fine. When I execute the sed command manually it does also work. Now I'm on an elementary os Juno with a slightly different image and the **docker version is 18.09.7**.

**My docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3"

networks:
    webnet:
services:
    web:
        image: wipster/relaunch:1
        depends_on:
            - db
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpus: '3.0'
                    memory: 2000M
                reservations:
                    cpus: '1.0'
                    memory: 1000M
        volumes:
            - ../relaunch:/var/www/html:delegated
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        networks:
            - webnet
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpus: '2.0'
                    memory: 1000M
                reservations:
                    cpus: '1.0'
                    memory: 500M
        volumes:
            - db_data_wipster:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wipster
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        networks:
            - webnet
        command: mysqld --sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION" --innodb-buffer-pool-size=536870912 --innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
volumes:
    db_data_wipster:
```

<strike>Am I missing anything? Do I need to run the sed command later?</strike> That doesn't work either.

Comment: Docker build cache?

Comment: I tried to build with --no-cache which did not work. I'm going to see if it works with different images.

Comment: You can try `cat /etc/apache2/envvars` and see the output while building the dockerfile to ensure it is what you expect.

Comment: The idea of Docker is to run Apache in the same way it is run on a production system. This means it runs with a dedicated user id. You want to run Apache with your user id, you do not need Docker. Just execute execute Apache on your system with the right configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a local development environment which will not be used elsewhere I just use a workaround.
I add my user, in this case "wipster", to the group www-data and change the file rights of the group.
The problem might occur because the user and group is hard coded in this particular image.

Answer (score 3):

You can verify the file is modified correctly by doing a grep:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN adduser wipster --disabled-password --disabled-login --gecos ""

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER wipster
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP wipster

RUN cat /etc/apache2/envvars | grep -B 2 -A 2 APACHE_RUN_USER

RUN sed -i "s#APACHE_RUN_USER:=.*#APACHE_RUN_USER:=wipster}#" /etc/apache2/envvars \
    && sed -i "s#APACHE_RUN_GROUP:=.*#APACHE_RUN_GROUP:=wipster}#" /etc/apache2/envvars

RUN cat /etc/apache2/envvars | grep -B 2 -A 2 APACHE_RUN_USER
```

And it indeed seems to make the change you intend:

```
Step 5/7 : RUN cat /etc/apache2/envvars | grep -B 2 -A 2 APACHE_RUN_USER
 ---> Running in 76aad84738a1
# settings are defined via environment variables and then used in apache2ctl,
# /etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, etc.
: ${APACHE_RUN_USER:=www-data}
export APACHE_RUN_USER
: ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP:=www-data}
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP
Removing intermediate container 76aad84738a1
 ---> 1be6e6068d73
Step 6/7 : RUN sed -i "s#APACHE_RUN_USER:=.*#APACHE_RUN_USER:=wipster}#" /etc/apache2/envvars     && sed -i "s#APACHE_RUN_GROUP:=.*#APACHE_RUN_GROUP:=wipster}#" /etc/apache2/envvars
 ---> Running in 75a741dadb34
Removing intermediate container 75a741dadb34
 ---> 6b2d9b0dfdac
Step 7/7 : RUN cat /etc/apache2/envvars | grep -B 2 -A 2 APACHE_RUN_USER
 ---> Running in 2555c019ab43
# settings are defined via environment variables and then used in apache2ctl,
# /etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, etc.
: ${APACHE_RUN_USER:=wipster}
export APACHE_RUN_USER
: ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP:=wipster}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to run apache in a docker container as the same user as the one I'm using on my host system.
>
> It does work with some Images and it doesn't work with others.

You must ensure that the user in the image/container has the same uid as the user on your host system. Thus in the Dockerfile you must provide the `--uid` option to the `adduser` command:

```
RUN adduser wipster --uid PUT_YOUR_UID_HERE --disabled-password --disabled-login --gecos ""
```

Note, that for the above to work the uid must not be in use by the docker image you're deriving your image from.

For more information see [Understanding how uid and gid work in Docker containers](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf)